# URL Encoding with NSCharcterSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, string, encoding

I have few video files and image files stored in applications directory.I was using **stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:** to convert into a legal URL string. Since it is deprecated and we are to use **stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:** instead, I am not able to get the correct URL for loading the pdf or playing the video. I tried all NSCharacterSet available. It is adding extra %252020 for a space and which is creating a problem.

Using **stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding**

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1392B0FE-F998-45A4-A398-A3ACB47ECE26/Library/Private%20Documents/Sample%20Image%20To%20Be%20Loaded.jpg

Using ** stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters**

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1392B0FE-F998-45A4-A398-A3ACB47ECE26/Library/Private%2520Documents/Sample%2520Image%2520To%2520Be%2520Loaded.jpg

And this couldn't find the file and hence couldn't load it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are the strings you are starting with?

Comment: **/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1392B0FE-F998-45A4-A398-A3ACB47ECE26/Library/Private Documents/Sample Image To Be Loaded.jpg**

Some url has square brackets in it like  **/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1392B0FE-F998-45A4-A398-A3ACB47ECE26/Library/Private Documents/Sample Image To Be Loaded_[12345679].jpg**

Comment: It is converting %20 to **%2520** and square bracket %5B to **%255B**

Comment: The way you get %2520 is when your url already has a %20 in it, and gets urlencoded again, which transforms the %20 to %2520.

Comment: Another example - **/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E1C0E3F8-673D-4360-A03B-2871CE4A25F0/Library/Private Documents/Summer Joy  [06821124RWeXf].jpg** is encoded as **file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E1C0E3F8-673D-4360-A03B-2871CE4A25F0/Library/Private%2520Documents/Summer%2520Joy%2520%255B06821124RWeXf%255D.jpg** I am using code something like this - **NSURL *urlToLoad = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [fullPath stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]]];**

Answer (score 1):

The way you get %2520 is when your url already has a %20 in it, and gets url-encoded again, which transforms the %20 to %2520. %255B is what you get when  you encode square bracket twice.

you can try the following code in en empty project:

```
NSString * str = @"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1392B0FE-F998-45A4-A398-A3ACB47ECE26/Library/Private Documents/Sample Image To Be Loaded.jpg";
NSString * encodedString = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"encodedString = %@", encodedString);
NSString * encodedStringAgain = [encodedString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"encodedStringAgain = %@", encodedStringAgain);
```

It prints:

> encodedString = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1392B0FE-F998-45A4-A398-A3ACB47ECE26/Library/Private%20Documents/Sample%20Image%20To%20Be%20Loaded.jpg
>
> encodedStringAgain = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1392B0FE-F998-45A4-A398-A3ACB47ECE26/Library/Private%2520Documents/Sample%2520Image%2520To%2520Be%2520Loaded.jpg

All you have to do in your code is :

```
NSURL *urlToLoad = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: fullPath];
```

With `fullPath` being the original string without any encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
NSString * encodedString = [@"stringURl to encode" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Didn't help. I tried all the NSCharacterset options. :(